# How to perform substring substitution when the substring contains the equal sign?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

In Windows Batch files, you can use this syntax to perform search&replace on variables:

```
set myvar=%myvar:foo=bar%
```

How to do this, however, when “foo” or “bar” include an equal sign? Escaping it with `^` does not seem to work…

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Escaping an equals sign in DOS batch string replacement command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499646/escaping-an-equals-sign-in-dos-batch-string-replacement-command)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of battling with cmd.exe's quirks, why not use vbscript instead?

```
Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments
strOld=objArgs(0)
strNew=objArgs(1)
str=Replace(WScript.StdIn.ReadAll,vbCrLf,"")
WScript.Echo Replace(str,strOld,strNew)
```

Save the above as replace.vbs

Usage:

```
C:\test>echo test| cscript //nologo replace.vbs te mi
mist
```

Comment: Or JScript or PowerShell or Perl or .... Lots of questions do deserve the "Don't do that, use this instead" type answers, I don't think this is one of them.

Comment: So ? If OP has no restrictions on what tools to use, he is free to adopt whatever solution he desires. Besides, I am only speaking the truth about cmd.exe's limitation and quirkiness.

Comment: Actually I do have restrictions on what my script may do because they will be deployed in a production environment on customer servers. I agree this would be really comfortable though.

Comment: Windows machines by default comes installed with vbscript.